# Why is my bootsrap carousel navigation not working?

Tags: css, navigation, carousel

```
   <div class="carousel slide ">
    <div class="carousel-inner " data-ride="carousel" id="featured"> 
     <div class="item active">   
         <img src="images/carousel-lifestyle.jpg" alt="Lifestyle Photo">
     </div>
     <div class="item">  
         <img src="images/carousel-mission.jpg" alt="Mission">
     </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="images/carousel-vaccinations.jpg" alt="Vaccinations">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="images/carousel-fish.jpg" alt="Fish">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="images/carousel-exoticanimals.jpg" alt="Exotic Animals">
      </div>



  <a href="#featured" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> <!--Previous button-->
  </a>
  <a href="#featured" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <!-- Next button-->
  </a>
  </div>      
</div>
```

*The next and previous navigation buttons are not working, though they are evident on the screen*
I can't figure out why the navigation of my carousel is not working.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `id` for your carousel.

```
<a href="#featured" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" role="button">
```

Your navigation links are referencing to an element having `id="featured"` but it is not anywhere in your markup.

Add `featured` as id to make your slider work:

```
<div id="featured" class="carousel slide">
//-------^^^^^^^^ this missing id causing your slider to not work properly.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="featured" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner " data-ride="carousel" id="featured"> 
     <div class="item active">   
         <img src="images/carousel-lifestyle.jpg" alt="Lifestyle Photo">
     </div>
     <div class="item">  
         <img src="images/carousel-mission.jpg" alt="Mission">
     </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="images/carousel-vaccinations.jpg" alt="Vaccinations">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="images/carousel-fish.jpg" alt="Fish">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="images/carousel-exoticanimals.jpg" alt="Exotic Animals">
      </div>



  <a href="#featured" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> <!--Previous button-->
  </a>
  <a href="#featured" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <!-- Next button-->
  </a>
  </div>      
</div>
```